# Should tomcat be changed to SSL mode if a web app in it must support connections to LDAPS?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, web-applications, active-directory, ldap

I have a web application that is deployed in tomcat. This web application must talk to an Active Directory over SSL (LDAPS url). Should the tomcat server.xml be changed to include an SSL connection? or tomcat's setting does not matter to the web app that sits in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two things are completely unrelated. One concerns outbound connections via LDAPS, the other concerns inbound connections via HTTPS.

However your Tomcat application should support HTTPS anyway.

Comment: it should still work if HTTPS is not enabled in tomcat at all and the web app tries to communicate LDAPS, correct?

Comment: What part of 'the two things are completely unrelated' didn't you understand?

Comment: ok, is there any configuration change needed in the web app's web.xml to support LDAPS? There are some references in forums related to adding "<security-constraint>" in web.xml. Is this or any other entry needed the xml? thank you.

Comment: `<security-constraint>'` relates, or can relate, to HTTPS, which has nothing to do with LDAPS whatsoever, as I've been telling you. There is nothing in `web.xml` that concerns LDAPS, but there should be something in `context.xml` that defines an `ldaps://` resource.